# How do I make vanilla sauce without air bubbles?

Tags: sauce, dessert, vanilla

Yesterday I made vanilla sauce to go with an apple pie. I used about 2 dl milk, 3 egg yolks and some sugar. I whisked it in a double boiler maybe too vigourously, because there were tiny bubbles of air in the finished sauce. It reached to correct consistency and otherwise was completely fine, but I would think vanilla sauce should have a relatively thick, rich consistency without any bubbles in it.

How can I do it better next time? Would heavy cream help? Should I not use a whisk and just stir with a spoon? How big of a risk is it that my sauce will curdle if I don't use a whisk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fold with a heat-safe silicone spatula, that will let you reach the whole surface of the pan so you don't get scorching, without introducing so many bubbles.

Or if you happen to have a vacuum machine, put your sauce in a bag after you make it and vacuum out all of the air. Voila, bubbles gone.

Comment: I thought that most vacuum packers die if you expose them to liquids?

Comment: spatula is not always a great idea, as it will scrape congealed bits off the sides, making your sauce... chewier than intended. Aaronut, that depends; professional-grade vacpacks can be used for liquids, you just need to cut a hole in the bag beyond where the seal will be so they don't explode everywhere.